# How can I override a trigger scripts for different triggers in Unity?

Tags: unity

I am trying to develope a story based game. And I developed my dialouge system (not an interactive system) with triggers.

It is like this

```
    public class Trigger : MonoBehaviour {
        public string text;
        public int variable; 
        void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {

          sayHi(text);

            }
         }        

         void sayHi(text){
          //some codes

          }
         finish(){
          //different code for different situations
         }
    }
```

I want to change that finish() method for different triggers. My idea is creating scripts for every trigger and make this class as parent class of it. Are there another option for it or is it the best way? Because I dont want to create hunderds of scripts for every triggers.

Another issue is that I must get a variable from main trigger script in my save script. It is like this:

```
GameObject[] triggerArray=GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Trigger");
for (int i = 0; i < triggerArray.Length; i++) {
   Trigger ts = (Trigger)(triggerArray [i].GetComponentInChildren<Trigger> ());
    return ts.variable;
}
```

While I can not write different save sripts for every trigger I can not get variable with this way if i override Trigger scripts. Because every child class of every trigger will have a different name.

By the way if my approach is not suitable for this purpose I am open for other suggestions.

Comment: Im not 100% sure i get everything you are trying to do. But it looks like you are trying to do something simple in a unnecessary complex way.

Comment: I am afraid you will have to write code for every different logic you need - how else would you know what to do? Where to put the code - it depends on what you want - from simplest switch on enum to more advanced delegates. But you have to put it *somewhere* should it be "script" in unity or method in same file.